# Error instantiating the custom FilterFactory class in Solr

Tags: java, solr

I have implemented a sample custom filter in Solr and configured the fieldtype:contentType to use the filter in indexing analysis phase as below ;

```
<fieldType name="contentType" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="com.solr.test.analyzer.ContentFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Below is my custom Filter factory class:

```
public class ContentFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

    public ContentFilterFactory() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
        return new ContentFilter(input);
    }

}
```

When starting the Solr 4.5.0 server I get the below error when loading ContentFilterFactory instance. The root cause is a 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.solr.test.analyzer.ContentFilterFactory.(java.util.Map)**

Do I need to include a init() method in the FilterFactory ? 
If so what should I include in it? Can someone please help me resolve this error.

```
   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'com.solr.test.analyzer.ContentFilterFactory'
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.readAnalyzer(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:400)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:151)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error instantiating class: 'com.solr.test.analyzer.ContentFilterFactory'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:556)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$3.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:382)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$3.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:376)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:151)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.solr.test.analyzer.ContentFilterFactory.<init>(java.util.Map)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:552)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: How did you exactly solve the problem by "using latest lucene-common library (4.5.0)" ? I'm having the same problem and I have only solr 4.6 dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: I used the lucene-analyzers-commons-4.5.0.jar which contains the required constructor of TokenFilterFactory class and got the issue resolved

Comment: I have the same problem. In my pom there is solrj and solr-core with all transitive dependencies like analyzers commons. There is no compilation problem until I run solr. "no init method"... Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [Javadoc for TokenFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/TokenFilterFactory.html) the constructor takes a `Map<String,String>` argument. Try updating your `ContentFilterFactory` constructor to be:

```java
public ContentFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
  super(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Condit. I got the issue resolved by using the latest lucene-common library (4.5.0) which contains above constructure API.